# Error Herencia Spring boot Heroku Postgress

Tags: postgresql, spring, jpa, heroku, herencia

He intentado varias formas de hacer un Estudiante y Docente que heredan de Usuario, cuando pido la lista de estudiantes, docentes o usuarios, de forma local sirve, pero debo desplegarlo en heroku y al desplegarlo los datos no llegan. De no poder usar la herencia (que como trabajo académico no se si este obligado a usarlo) mi unica solución es hacer la tabla estudiante y docente por separado sin la herencia,

Estoy usando spring boot, jpa y la base de datos es postgresql de heroku.

Clase Usuario

```
package co.com.sergio.bkterrymathmand.entity;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;

@Entity
@Table(name = "usuario")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "dtype", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
public class Usuario implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "idusuario")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
    private int idusuario;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String nombre;

    public int getIdusuario() {
        return idusuario;
    }

    public void setIdusuario(int idusuario) {
        this.idusuario = idusuario;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }
}
```

Clase Estudiante

```
package co.com.sergio.bkterrymathmand.entity;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;


@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "estudiante")
public class Estudiante extends Usuario{

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "estudiante")
  private List<Respuesta> respuestas;

  /* Getter y Setter */
  public List<Respuesta> getRespuestas() {
    return respuestas;
  }

  public void setRespuestas(List<Respuesta> respuestas) {
    this.respuestas = respuestas;
  }
}
```

Clase docente

```
package co.com.sergio.bkterrymathmand.entity;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.DiscriminatorValue;
import javax.persistence.Entity;


@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "docente")
public class Docente extends Usuario {

  @Column(nullable = false)
  private String correo;

  /* Getter y Setter */

  public String getCorreo() {
    return correo;
  }

  public void setCorreo(String correo) {
    this.correo = correo;
  }
}
```

Json de http://localhost:8080/estudiante

```
{
   "data":[
      {
         "idusuario":1,
         "nombre":"sergio rodriguez",
         "respuestas":[
            
         ]
      }
   ],
   "success":true,
   "message":"Lista de estudiantes obtenida con éxito"
}
```

Json de https://bk-terrymathmand.herokuapp.com/estudiante

```
{
   "data":[
      
   ],
   "success":true,
   "message":"Lista de estudiantes obtenida con éxito"
}
```